# The document has no pages when create pdf file with itextsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, itext

I am using the below code to export html to PDF;

this code good work in localhost but my web return error;

i have checked and see pdf created but not read and write and this file empty;

also i traced and see GetCssFile worked and read this file;

```
var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create));
                pdfWriter.RgbTransparencyBlending = true;
                pdfDoc.AddAuthor("awattelc");
                pdfDoc.Open();
                var html = @"
                        <code id='one'>
                        فروشگاه</span>
                        <br>
                        <span id='f2'>
                        فاکتور فروش </span><br/><span id='f3'>صورتحساب آقای/خانم:" + daoOrderEydanheCampaign.BOAddress.FirstName + "</span><br/><span id='f4'>کد: 10000</span><br/><span id='f5'>شماره:315</span><br/><span id='f6'>تاریخ:" + date + "</span></code><code><table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2' class='tablePDF'><thead><tr><th>ردیف</th><th>کدکالا</th><th>نام کالا</th><th>تعداد</th><th>واحد</th><th>بهای واحد</th><th>مبلغ کل</th><th>شرح کالا</th></tr></thead><tbody>" +
                            trs +
                            "<tr id='tr'><td colspan='3'>جمع کل فاکتور</td><td colspan='1'>" + cntProd.ToString() + "عدد</td><td colspan='4'>" + string.Format("{0:n0}", SumTotalPrice) + "تومان</td></tr><tr id='tr'><td colspan='3'>جمع کل فاکتور به حروف</td><td colspan='5'>" + Global.GetPersianWordsByNumber(SumTotalPrice.ToString()) + "</td></tr><tr id='tr'><td>توضیحات</td><td colspan='7'></td></tr><tr id='tr'><td colspan='8'>آدرس:327</td></tr><tr id='tr'><td colspan='8'>تلفن:-فکس:</td></tr></tbody></table>< br/></code>";
                html = html.ToXHtml();
                var cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
                try
                {
                    var serverPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/pdf/PdfCreatorStyle.css");
                    cssResolver.AddCss(XmlWorkerUtils.GetCssFile(serverPath));
                    css = "YES";
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
                cssResolver.AddCss(@"                                   
                                code#one 
                                 {
                                    text-align: center;
                                    margin: 0 auto;
                                    font-size: 0.6em;
                                    width: 100%;
                                    direction: rtl;
                                    font-family: 0 Yekan;
                                    border:solid 1px #e4e4e4;
                                 }",
                    "utf-8", true);
                var elementsHandler = new ElementsCollector();
                var htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(new CssAppliersImpl(new UnicodeFontProvider()));
                htmlContext.SetImageProvider(new ImageProvider());
                htmlContext.CharSet(Encoding.UTF8);
                htmlContext.SetAcceptUnknown(true)
                    .AutoBookmark(true)
                    .SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
                var pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver,
                    new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new ElementHandlerPipeline(elementsHandler, null)));
                var worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, parseHtml: true);
                var parser = new XMLParser();
                parser.AddListener(worker);
                parser.Parse(new StringReader(html));
                var mainTable = new PdfPTable(1) { WidthPercentage = 100, RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL };
                var cell = new PdfPCell
                {
                    Border = 0,
                    RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL,
                    HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
                };
                cell.AddElement(elementsHandler.Paragraph);
                mainTable.AddCell(cell);
                pdfDoc.Add(mainTable);
                Process.Start(fileName);
```

Any suggestion how to fix it?

Comment: Your document is probably completely emtpy, that's why you're getting this message.

Comment: you forgot to close `pdfDoc` before you try to use the created pdf.